# How to write a Butcher tableau from a Runge-Kutta method

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I am failing to understand how to write a Runge-Kutta method, such as the example below into a Butcher tableau.

A uniform s-stage Runge-Kutta method for the scalar initial-value problem

$$\frac{du}{dt}=f(t,u)$$
$$u(0)=u_0$$

is given by the following:

- Let $U^0:=u(0)$
- For each $i = 1,\dots, s$ compute $p_i$ such that

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad p_i=U^n+\tau\sum_{j=1}^s a_{ij}f(t_n+\tau c_j, p_j)\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(1)$$

- Finally, set

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad U^{n+1}=U^n+\tau\sum_{i=1}^s b_{i}f(t_n+c_i\tau, p_i) \quad\quad\quad\quad(2)$$

Write the method $(1)–(2)$ in the form of a Butcher tableau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a first step to get the perhaps better recognizable form of a Runge-Kutta method, write
$$
k_i=\tau f(t_n+\tau c_i, p_i)=\tau f(t_n+c_i\tau, U_n+\sum_{j=1}^s a_{ij}k_j)
$$
Then also 
$$
U_{n+1}=U_n+\sum_{i=1}^s b_ik_i.
$$
The Butcher tableau is then, with the already conventionally named coefficients,
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
c_1&a_{11}&\dots&a_{1s}\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
c_s&a_{s1}&\dots&a_{ss}\\
\hline
&b_1&\dots&b_s
\end{array}
$$